# Convert float number string to German equivalent string with C#

Tags: c#

I want to convert "-1.775" to German "-1,775". How to do it using C# ?

I tried

```cs
string abc = "-1.775";

Convert.ToDouble(abc).ToString("F3");
```

This results me `"-1775,000`"

I am Running my application on a German OS.

Comment: what have you [***tried yourself***](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information.
  i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Parsing methods and string conversion methods typically takes a [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0) object to define how numbers should be represented. I would suggest starting there.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the value is originally some kind of numeric type, for example:

```
double nDouble = -1.775;
decimal nDecimal = -1.775m;
float nFloat = -1.775f;
```

...you can use the `ToString(IFormatProvider)` method of the type with a specified culture. For example:

```
string strDouble = nDouble.ToString(new CultureInfo("de"));
string strDecimal = nDecimal.ToString(new CultureInfo("de"));
string strFloat = nFloat.ToString(new CultureInfo("de"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:0.0}", -1.775);
```